# Is it possible that the size of the filesystem reported by df grows over night?

Tags: filesystems, rhel, disk-usage

I have noticed something strange to me on a RHEL 8.3 Linux system I am only a guest on. I do have `sudo` privileges and install occasionally software.

I wanted to install some software into `/opt` (to keep it isolated from `/usr/local`, but still well accessible for multiple users).

When I looked at the mounted filesystems *before the install*, `df` reported something like this (note the numbers for `/opt`):

```
[...]
/dev/mapper/sys_vg-root_lv   5.0G  3.0G  2.1G  60% /
[...]
/dev/mapper/sys_vg-home_lv   2.0G  1.4G  669M  68% /home
/dev/mapper/sys_vg-tmp_lv    4.0G   61M  4.0G   2% /tmp
[...]
/dev/mapper/sys_vg-opt_lv    1.0G  292M  710M  29% /opt
[...]
```

Then *after the install* into `/opt` I ran df again:

```
[...]
/dev/mapper/sys_vg-opt_lv    1.0G  443M  630M  44% /opt
[...]
```

I was a bit worried when doing more installs into `/opt` in the coming weeks this might run out space.

However *one day later* `df` showed this:

```
[...]
/dev/mapper/sys_vg-opt_lv    1.5G  443M  1.1G  29% /opt
[...]
```

The filesystem seem to have grown overnight! Was there likely a human sysadmin involved or is this somehow an automatic standard behaviour configurable on Linux filesystems?

#### Note:

The file system of the `/opt` tree is `xfs`.

Comment: I've not seen this before but I wonder if it has something to do with LVM.  Perhaps copy-on-write behaviour or similar. Have you tried running "fstrim" on /opt ?  What filesystem is /opt formatted with? btrfs has some compression options which may cause fun results with df

Comment: "this somehow an automatic standard behaviour configurable on Linux filesystems?" ... not that I know of. Your sysadmin likely saw the disk usage just bumped up the free space for you. Why don't you check with them?

Comment: @PhilipCouling Thanks for your ideas, I will check on Monday what FS is used.

Comment: @PhilipCouling The filesystem is `xfs`. Anyway that `xfs` can grow automatically?

Comment: Just ask your system administrator. They can answer this definitively.

Answer (score 0):

> Was there likely a human sysadmin involved or is this somehow an automatic standard behaviour configurable on Linux filesystems.

This was a human intervention. Filesystems in Linux don't automatically resize themselves. What you're talking about sounds like AI and I've not heard of any AI present in the Linux kernel.

Also, this look could be considered a fuzzy undetermined behaviour no one would want to deal with.

Comment: Well, I think the idea of an auto-resizing mechanism is not that far fetched, but I'm not an filesystem expert...